# how to select div class by find_element_by_xpath?

Tags: python, html, class, select, instagram

I'm making instagram like bot, but I can not find the element for the post in #tag page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSpop.jpg)

Red circle is what I want to click it, and the inspected element is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DFYT.png)

my code is

```
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[2]')

e.click()
```

but it didn't work. how do I select this element?

Comment: What error are you getting exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first, you need to know that, the inspection you're doing on your chrome is not going to be the same when running a new instance of your program due to generated css class, so that can be the first problem !
The second problem is that, it's possible you just got blocked by instagram because you're it detected that you're not a 'real' browser.

There can be many reasons !
So first, make sure you can get the whole html and it has the same structure as the one you're trying to fetch/scrap !